# CSS - Button:focus doesn´t allow me to click on link

Tags: html, css

I´m trying to make a Website, when I click on "Menu", it shows me the navbar with the links. When I try to click on one of the link they suddently disappear. I know **it´s because the focused button is not targed anymore** but how can I make it that it let me click there?
**Some picture to let you understand it better -->**
[Closed Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPab5.png) -
[Opened Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gb6an.png)
**Some CSS for styling are maybe missing but that´s the one who gives me problem**

```css
    nav {display: none;
        height: 13em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 1em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 1em;
    }
        

    
        .navbutton {
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            width: 30%;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            color: #1b5e20;
            padding-top: 0.2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-left:35%;
            margin-bottom: 0.5em;
            border-radius: 1em;
            font-size: 100%;
            background-color: white;
    }
    
    button {height: 3em;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #1b5e20;
        color: white;
        transition: 0.3s;
        display: block;
        border-style: none;}

    .menu   {font-family: sans-serif;
                     text-align: center;
                     margin-left: 0 auto;
                     margin-right: 0 auto;
                     background-color: white;
                    border-radius: 1em;
                    color:white;
                    background-color: #4c8c4a;
                    padding-left: 1em;
                    padding-right: 1em;
                    font-size: 1.6em;
            }
    
    .close {
            display:inline;
            text-align: center;
            text-decoration: none;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            color: white;
            padding: 0.3em;
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-left:48%;
            margin-top: 5%;
            border-radius: 100em;
            background-color: darkred;
            cursor: pointer;
    }
    .close:hover, .close:active {display: none;}
```

```html
<html lang="de" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Mediterrane Pflanzen Alongi - Photogallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="design.css" />

    <style>

        button:active+nav, button:focus+nav {display: block;}
        button:active+nav, button:focus+nav {display: block;}
                                           
    </style>
</head>
  <body>

<button> 
    <a class="menu">Menu</a>
</button>

    <nav class="navbar">
    <a class="navbutton" href="mediterrane pflanzen home.html">Home</a>
 <a class="navbutton" href="mediterrane%20pflanzen%20photogallery.html">Galerie</a>
    <a class="navbutton" href="mediterrane pflanzen kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    <a class="navbutton" href="mediterrane%20pflanzen%20uber%20uns.html">&Uuml;ber uns</a>
    <a class="navbutton" href="mediterrane%20pflanzen%20impressum.html">Impressum</a>
    <a class="close">X</a>
    </nav>
```

Comment: Don't use focus as a hack to toggle the display of something. Use JavaScript and set appropriate ARIA attributes.

Comment: Please note that using hover breaks your site for those of us who primarily use mobile devices. My phone and tablet don't do hover.

Comment: Why do you have twice spelled out in your code - `button: active + nav, button: focus + nav {display: block;}` ?

Comment: I would recommend using a checkbox to open / close the menu. In this case, javascript is not needed. And there will be no problem with focusing either.